# Rails: How to "publish" a website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

So, I am almost done with my website. I created it using ruby on rails on the Cloud9 IDE. Is there a way to publish it? To go on it, a user has to be signed on Cloud9 and then I need to run the code on the terminal...

```
rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
```

How would I be able to publish my website? I am very new to rails and I have no idea.

Comment: You can [deploy to heroku](https://docs.c9.io/docs/deploying-via-cli) from cloud9.

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-deploying

Answer (score 2):

To publish your website you need to host it somewhere.

There are multiple ways to do this. For instance you can use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). They provide PaaS (Platform as a service), which means they will handle the installation of the app for you and the maintenance of the virtual machine it resides (updates and whatnot).

Heroku also gives you a very nice admin view for the status of your app, online log display and some other goodies.

Another alternative would be [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/), [DigitalOcean](https://www.linode.com/) or Linode (among many others!). They provide IaaS(Infrastructure as a Service). They only give you a virtual machine with your choice of operating system, you will have to manually publish your app and provide manual maintenance of the VM and pretty much anything including the database itself.

Using Heroku would be your best choice for the moment as they are very straightforward with the publishing part. Once you get the grip you can go to the other platforms for customization.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need some deployment tools such as capistrano or mina.

If you're going to host your app in heroku, it's much easier to deploy. As simple as pushing your codes with git.